# Drag and drop dialog box missing for some users

Tags: 2010, document-library

In a document "Upload Multiple Document link is clicked, instead of getting "Drag files and folders" dialog box some users are getting "browse for files". The users needs the drag files option. How can i resolve it?
 Thanks in advance.
-----------
 Vijay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag-drop functionality works for x32 IE only because of some ActiveX objects. Tell them users to use x32 IE. Not x64 IE, Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. we had the problem sorted out. The user had both office 2003 and office 2010 installed in his machine."STSUPLD.DLL" file was taken from office2003 which don't support drag files. Uninstalling office 2003 and repairing office 2010 solved the issue.Thanks for your time.